# Promise returning undefined variable

Tags: node.js

Yes, I've tried other solutions I have found but to no avail. I've tried setting a variable (region) above the promise but realized that it'd be out of the scope so this was my next solution. Whenever I try to return region it comes back as undefined. Whenever I console.log it (in the same place) it works just fine. Any insight to this?

EDIT: iplocation is an npm package [iplocation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/iplocation)

```
function getRegion(ipAddr) {
    iplocation(ipAddr)
        .then(res => {
            if (res.country == 'US') {
                region = res.country + "-" + states[res.region_code];
            } else {
                region = res.country;
            }
            return region;
        })
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
async function getRegion (ipAddr) {
  let res
  try {
    res = await iplocation(ipAddr)
    if (res.country === 'US') {
      return `${res.country} - ${states[res.region_code]}`
    } else {
      return res.country
    }
  } catch (err) {
    throw err
  }
}
```

Usage:

```
getRegion('8.8.8.8')
  .then(loc => console.log(loc))
  .catch(err => console.log(err))
```

Comment: So basically I  need to take what "loc" would equal and assign it to something in an object preferably outside the promise.

Comment: Nevermind, I added the object to the promise and got it to work. Thanks!

Comment: There's really no need for `await` here and you've "eaten" the error and are returning `err` as if it was a country.  This is not proper error handling.

Comment: What you are missing is the `async` nature of `node.js`. Code would not be executed from top to down. It could be executed in any order depending on the code. That's the big difference from languages like C.

Comment: Why do you even have the `try/catch` when all you're doing in the catch is `throw err`?  Code would be simpler without it.  The `async` function will catch any exception of rejected promise and propagate it to the caller as a rejected promise.  You don't have to do that manually.

Comment: @jfriend00: For the sake of learning.

Answer (score 0):

Promises run asynchronously. That means by the time the `.then` part is run, the outer function has returned undefined. You could make the outer function `async` and then `await` the value of the Promise.

Comment: So async the getRegion function then await the iplocation promise? If I do that I just get `Promise { <pending> }`

Answer (score 0):

Your operation is asynchronous so you need to return a promise and the caller needs to use `.then()` with it:

```
function getRegion(ipAddr) {
    // return the promise
    return iplocation(ipAddr).then(res => {
        // return value will be resolved value of the promise
        if (res.country == 'US') {
            return res.country + "-" + states[res.region_code];
        } else {
            return res.country;
        }
    });
}

getRegion(...).then(region => {
  // use the region in here
  console.log(region);
}).catch(err => {
  // handle error here
  console.log(err):
});
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to return the promise you are awaiting. You could use `return new Promise(...)` or use `async/await` as seen below.

```
async function getRegion(ipAddr) {
   const res = await iplocation(ipAddr)
   if (res.country == 'US') {
     return res.country + "-" + states[res.region_code];
   }
   return res.country;
}
```

Comment: Please explain your code and how it solves the OP's question.